# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: php, composer-php

I need some help
I have been trying to install composer https://getcomposer.org/download/
and the installer keeps giving me the error

```html
The PHP exe file you specified did not run correctly:
C:\xampp\php\php.exe

The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini

A setting in your php.ini could be causing the problem: Either the 'extension_dir' value is incorrect or the dll does not exist.

Program Output:
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_intl.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
 in Unknown on line 0
```

Version : XAMMP Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.6.3

What I have tried before:

- Install Miscrosoft Visual C++ Redistributable (failed)
- change patch to php (failed)

Comment: Go to php.ini file file `extension=php_intl.dll` and remove `;` from start of the line and restart your apeache server.

Comment: Extension is already enable extension=php_intl.dll on my php.ini.